# Footer in Vue js start page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, footer

I need to add a footer to the Vue js project home page. But it is not working, i dont konw more about vue, I'm a begineer.

[I need to add footer to this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCPLX.png)

This is my footer component:

```
<template>
 <footer>
 </footer>
</template>

<style scoped>

footer
{
display: flex;
background-color: #42b942; 
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;}
</style>
```

This is my code in App.vue:

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import footer from '@/components/footer.vue';

    export default {
  name: "footer",
  components: {
    footer
   }
 }
 </script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

What are changes to get the footer in the open page of the vue project.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't placed your footer component anywhere in your app template. Also don't name your app "footer" when you're importing another component with the same name.

Assuming you want the footer to be visible on all pages of your app try modifying it like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
    <footer/> <!-- Here we place the footer -->
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
import footer from '@/components/footer.vue';

export default {
  name: "myApp", // Renaming the app so it won't conflict with the child component
  components: {
    footer
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It's not working. There is no change on the page. The footer is not visible.

Comment: Is it because your `footer.vue` component template is empty? Try placing some text in it.

Comment: yes i modified the footer.vue. Stll no change

Comment: <template>
    <div>
        <p>amith</p>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

footer
{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #42b942; 
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;

}
</style>

Comment: like this i changed it

Comment: Try to add 'bottom: 0;' to footer style, and place footer component like akopyl answered

Comment: I will post the app.vue as the answer. can you please check it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
    <footer/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import footer from '@/components/footer.vue';

export default {
  name: "myApp",
  components: {
    footer
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You said in one of your replies that after modification your footer.vue looks like this but your style will go to html tag footer which doesn't exist in the template so it could be that the component foorter is shown in App.vue but not as a footer but only the word "amith"

```
<template> 
  <div> 
   <p>amith</p>
  </div> 
</template> 

<style scoped> 
footer 
{ display: flex; 
background-color: #42b942; 
height: 50px; 
width: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
} 
</style>
```

So maybe change it do this:

```
<template> 
 <footer>
  <div> 
   <p>amith</p>
  </div> 
 </footer>
</template> 

<style scoped> 
footer { 
display: flex; 
background-color: #42b942; 
height: 50px; 
width: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
} 
</style>
```

Also change the footer component name in the import since it makes problems when the name is the same as a ta

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
    <footerComp /> <!-- Here we place the footer -->
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
import footerComp from '@/components/footer.vue';

export default {
  name: "myApp", // Renaming the app so it won't conflict with the child component
  components: {
    footerComp
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I changed to how you suggested, then also there is no change in the page. it is the same as the picture, I shared. There is any other way for this, can you please help.

Comment: @AmithBino Also I think it makes problem that your import component is named the same as a real tag. I updated my answer with the changed code.